# Oracle's (+) notation within function

Tags: oracle, join

If we use `(+)` notation we can have outer join. For example:

```
select *
from tab_a, tab_b
where tab_a.num = tab_b.num(+)
```

Is outer join.
If we use function around columns, for example:

```
select *
from tab_a, tab_b
where round(tab_a.num, 2) = round(tab_b.num(+), 2)
```

Is it still outer join? Or is it becomes inner join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it still outer join? Or is it becomes inner join?

It is still an outer join:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5da63/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table tab_a(num integer);
create table tab_b(num integer);

insert into tab_a(num) values(1);
insert into tab_a(num) values(2);

insert into tab_b(num) values(2);
insert into tab_b(num) values(3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from tab_a, tab_b
where tab_a.num = tab_b.num(+)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5da63/2/0)**:

```
| NUM |    NUM |
|-----|--------|
|   2 |      2 |
|   1 | (null) |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select *
from tab_a, tab_b
where round(tab_a.num, 2) = round(tab_b.num(+), 2)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5da63/2/1)**:

```
| NUM |    NUM |
|-----|--------|
|   2 |      2 |
|   1 | (null) |
```